# Paging Library 3 and prefetchDistance usage

Tags: android, android-paging-library

I am using androidx.paging:paging-*:3.0.0-alpha13

I have such configs for pagination

```
        PagingConfig(
        pageSize = LOAD_SIZE,
        enablePlaceholders = false,
        initialLoadSize = LOAD_SIZE,
        prefetchDistance = 2 )
```

I need to load just 'one page' during start (I know that this is not too good practice, but this is required for my case)
Despite prefetchDistance = 2 I can see that PageKeyedRemoteMediator loads two pages.
Why does it loads second page if prefetch size is too small and visible items at screen just 2-3 and how to make him to load just `one page` at start

Comment: have u tried set prefetchDistance to 1?